# How do I specify where git looks for its configuration file?

Tags: windows, git

I am running git (i.e., Git-1.9.0-preview20140217) under Windows 7. The Git bash shell works fine: I can clone my github repository without issues. However, when I run the Git GUI and try to clone the exact same repository I get the following error:

```
Failed to create repository C:/Users/<my username here>/workspace/foo:
fatal: unable to access '"C:\Users\<my username here>"/.config/git/config':
Invalid argument
```

Based on the following link...

http://git-scm.com/book/ch1-5.html

...it looks like Git wants to look for a configuration file under my `%USERPROFILE%` and I can verify that the git clone is definitely pulling the right value out of the `%USERPROFILE%` environment variable. However it looks like the combination of forward and backslashes is causing the file open to fail on my Windows 7 machine. Things I have tried:

1. Created a `.config\git\config` file in the appropriate directory - no help
2. verified that I have a valid `.gitconfig` file under the directory pointed to by my `%USERPROFILE%` environment variable.
3. Tried downloading Source Tree. Performing a git clone from the Source Tree UI results in the same error.

Comment: Did you edit out your username from the error message?  Or is it legitimately looking in `C:/Users`?  I assume that `C:/Users` is not your `%USERPROFILE`?

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue.
I started using 'Git Bash' (http://msysgit.github.io/img/gw1.png). All git commands are working fine.